# Не работает телеграм бот что делать?

Tags: python, telebot, config

Бот попугай не работает

```
import telebot
import config

bot=telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,message.text)

    #RUN
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Функция bot.polling() у вас вызывается в хендлере сообщения. Вынесите вызов за пределы функции lalala():

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def lalala(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat_id, message.text)
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```